# Excel VBA - link rows from different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, copy, selection

Scenario: I can't post the actual workbook due to sensitive materials but I'll explain it as best as possible.

Each Sheet is divided into branches i.e.: Sheet2 is Branch 2, Sheet3 is Branch 3 and so on.
For each sheet the column are the same.
Column A has the branch number in it.
Column B has irrelevant information so i just hide that column.
Column C has a system number (specific to each account.

Intention: I want to create another sheet called `CallOuts`.
I want to copy some rows (from various branches) and paste them onto the 'Master sheet' (`CallOuts`) I can work on the `CallOuts` sheet instead of going to each branch. So that whenever I edit a cell it will also update/change that exact same cell in the branch sheet and vise versa with the master sheet.

Problem: I know MS Exccel has a "Paste Special" function where it adds the cell. The problem with that is it links the cell# so if I sort the Master sheet it will replace the row into the wrong branch sheet.

E.g.: If System# J112 is in branch 2 sheet, row 2 and I have the link pasted in Row 4 in the master sheet, if I make updates on the Master sheet and then re-sort it and the System# now moves to Row 2 (on the master sheet) whatever is in Row 4(on the master) will now be in Row 2, Branch 2 sheet.

I was thinking maybe a macro where I could copy and paste the entire row from the master sheet. Do some type of case selection to check which branch is in column A and then find the same system # on the branch sheet then paste the whole row.

My VBA level is novice at best so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So I saw your attempt below. I am not sure how your code works but it seems like you were on the right track. However, I don't think the Case syntax is appropriate for this situation. You simply need a macro that will read what is in your "CallOuts" sheet and use that data to update your individual branch sheets. This macro should work for you:

```
Sub UpdateRecordsFromMasterSheet()

Dim wksht As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim row As Range
Dim Row_to_Update As Range

Dim sysnum As Variant

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each row In Sheets("CallOuts").UsedRange.Rows
    row.EntireRow.Copy
    sysnum = row.Cells(1, 3).Value
    For Each wksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each Row_to_Update In wksht.UsedRange.Rows
            If Row_to_Update.Cells(1, 3).Value = sysnum Then
                Row_to_Update.PasteSpecial
            End If
        Next Row_to_Update
    Next wksht
Next row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This assumes you have your system number in column "C". So here is what I am imagining: Each time you assign an employee a bunch of rows - your employee updates those rows - and then you paste that data back into the "CallOuts" sheet. Then you run this macro and it will update the individual branch sheets based on what is in the "CallOuts" sheet.

If your a visual person here is how it will look:

Here is the updated callouts sheet:
[image: CallOutsSheet]

Here is how the branches will look before the macro:
[image: BeforeMacro]

Here is the updated branch after the macro runs:
[image: AfterMacro]

Try it out and let me know how it works. Note: this is just a start to show you how to do something like this - you could make this process more efficient by having the macro loop through the actual workbooks that the employees submit to you so you wouldn't have to copy and paste the data into your "CallOuts" sheet every time. Good Luck.

Comment: Okay, so I'll try to explain the layout as best I can. 
Each sheet is the branch #, and all branches have Row 1 as this header: ColumnA = Br#(Branch#); ColB = 2 option dropdown list; ColC = CS#(Customer System#); ColD = Last date checked; ColE = Status of account (dropdown menu) and then ColF to Z are account specific info like phone number, name and so on.
In col E is the status of the account with a dropdown menu; one of the statuses is "call required", where we have to contact the customer. There are over 10,000 accounts spread out over 84 branches.

Comment: I'd like to have all the "call required" accounts to be put onto another sheet so I can have someone make the calls.
If the call gets completed then I'd edit the status.
The vise versa part I'm referring to is if I make an edit on the branch sheet it will automatically change it on the master sheet too. But this part is not necessary if I can somehow reverse the effect later when I no longer require the master sheet.

Comment: The main issue I'm concerned with is sometimes I will require sorting the master sheet. If I use the "paste link" special in excel, the system# will no longer be in the correct branch sheet.
So I was thinking maybe a macro that I could execute when I need to update the branch sheets, where the macro would copy the entire row of data (in the master) figure out which branch it's from and find the matching system# in that sheet then paste the entire row. Then it would go back to the master sheet and do the next one.

Comment: So it seems like you are trying to find a way to allow someone(or many people) to do data entry on a list of account information. And then later on merge that data into a master workbook of account information-and to do this without creating duplicate rows of data with different information. This is a common problem in many programming situations "How do multiple users edit the same information?" "Which one should take precedence?". The most common answer is not that complicated. They let one user edit something at one time -they lock other users out of that something until that user is done.

Comment: So you have a few options. Now one way you could do this with Excel is you could split all your branches up into seperate workbooks - that way you could assign each person a branch and they would only deal with that branch. Later on, there are macros that could Merge all the seperate workbooks together again into one workbook. And if you wanted - there are macros that merge all sheets in a workbook into one sheet. So if you wanted to do that you could do that. I am assuming you are going to have multiple people doing this at the same time. So this is what I would recommend as the best option.

Comment: If you don't want to split up your workbook, then and only then would I recommend that you write a macro that will read from a sheet a list of new account information and overide the old information.

Comment: No I don't want to split it up. All I would like to do is have hit run and the macro would copy the row from the mastersheet, find the branch sheet it belongs to then find the specific row that system # is in and then paste the row from the mastersheet onto that specific branch sheet and specific sys# row.